# Create GraphicsDevice for custom driver

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, headless

I'm working on a project using Java in an embedded system. I have drivers for the screen and touch input, and a virtual keyboard for text input. My screen driver has a `Graphics2D` object you can draw into and a `repaint(Rectangle)` method for updating. Similarly, the touch driver is capable of generating `MouseEvents` for listeners.

Right now I'm working with drawing directly to the screen. This is fine, but what I really want is to allow the user of my library to create a JFrame and use normal Swing elements. However, the default GraphicsEnvironment is headless, since Java doesn't see my `EInkDriver` class or my `TouchDriver` class.

I'm aware that there are ways to call a component's `paint` method to get the image; however this has problems when you're painting a `Container`, and I'd also like to present the user with a `GraphicsConfiguration` so they can write something like `JFrame frame = new JFrame(getEInkGraphicsConfiguration());` and carry on as if they were writing a desktop Swing app.

Given these capabilities that I already have, how would I go about creating a `GraphicsDevice` or `GraphicsEnvironment` that would allow me to use Swing in my project?

Answer (score 1):

I took a very short look at the abstract class [GraphicsEnvironment](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.java.html), and guess, one may derive ones own class, and use the "java.awt.graphicsenv" key of line 64 to register it.

Fortunately there is an abstract class, and the code is little.

---

***Thereafter***

The following code from GraphicsEnvironment shows:

1. System properties (you may set) that are used for headless or not.
2. The environment setting DISPLAY.

Maybe you can use this info.

```
                        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
                        if (osName.contains("OS X") && "sun.awt.HToolkit".equals(
                                System.getProperty("awt.toolkit")))
                        {
                            headless = defaultHeadless = Boolean.TRUE;
                        } else {
                            headless = defaultHeadless =
                                Boolean.valueOf(("Linux".equals(osName) ||
                                                 "SunOS".equals(osName) ||
                                                 "FreeBSD".equals(osName) ||
                                                 "NetBSD".equals(osName) ||
                                                 "OpenBSD".equals(osName)) &&
                                                 (System.getenv("DISPLAY") == null));
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm more interested in the specifics of "deriving one's own class." If I can derive the class then I can use it by calling `JFrame(GraphicsConfiguration)`. However I'm stuck as to how to actually derive that class. I was thinking of overwriting `GraphicsDevice.getFullScreenWindow()` but I can't create a `Window` without a `GraphicsEnvironment` leaving me with a chicken-and-the-egg problem.

Comment: I did not really look into it, no guarantee, but I thought of the setting `java.awt.graphicsenv=my.packge.MyGraphicsEnvironmentChild`.

Comment: I understood that part... it doesn't explain how to actually implement `my.packge.MyGraphicsEnvironmentChild` though. If I could implement that class then I wouldn't need to set that property since I could just call `JFrame(new MyGraphicsEnvironmentChild())`. Your answer assumes I can implement this class, which I can't--that's what my question is asking. So unfortunately your answer doesn't help.