# Using Swing with a framebuffer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, headless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create GraphicsDevice for custom driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895614/create-graphicsdevice-for-custom-driver)

I'm working on writing Swing apps for my Kobo Touch. Unfortunately, Java on the Kobo does not recognize the default screen is at `/dev/fb0` and instead tells me I'm in a headless environment. This means I can't use `java.awt.Window` or its descendants. I've asked a related but different question as well: [Create GraphicsDevice for custom driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895614/create-graphicsdevice-for-custom-driver).

I should mention that I'm using Java due to the fact that I haven't been able to set up my laptop to cross-compile, so unfortunately I can't write my own C++ driver.

Can anyone tell me how to notify Swing that the screen is available an `/dev/fb0`?